# I am getting error while installing the requirements using the command pip install -r requirement.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

I have downloaded my friend's repo for some modifications but when I tried to install the requirements from requirement.txt using `pip install -r requirement.txt`, I got error saying

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" install -r requirement.txt': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
c:\program files\python38\python.exe  -m C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe install -r requirement.txt
```

which is equivalent to `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`